# How to explicitly set the height of the root html element to the minimum of the viewport and page content

Tags: html, css

There are a lot of similar questions to this, but no solution covers all the bases. (Please read before closing!)

My goal:

- If there isn't very much content on the page, the root html element will fill the entire viewport.
- If there is a lot of content on the page, the root html element will expand and be as tall as the page content.
- The height of the root html element must be explicitly defined (see [definition](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/height)) so that sub-elements can use percentage css statements like `height: 100%`.

Here are two JS fiddles to demonstrate what I mean. I'm looking for a single set of css rules that works for both examples:

- [Not very much page content](http://jsfiddle.net/QtQ2v/)
- [More page content](http://jsfiddle.net/pb3C5/1/)

Examples with side menus to demonstrate why (3) is important. I want the sidemenu height to match the height of the content:

- [Not very much page content](http://jsfiddle.net/QtQ2v/1/)
- [More page content](http://jsfiddle.net/pb3C5/2/)

Comment: `body { min-height: 100% }`?

Comment: This was one of my first thoughts as well - it works for the `body` element, but ultimately the body's height is dependent on the `html`'s. This fails (1), assuming you have no css on your html node . Otherwise it fails (2) if you have `html { height: 100% }` and fails (3) if you have `html { min-height: 100% }`

Answer (score 3):

change `#content { height: 100%; }` to `#content { min-height: 100%; }`.

Comment: Neat, works for the JSFiddles! Unfortunately it doesn't quite answer the question. I'd like the height of `#content` to propagate upwards to the root element so that other elements can scale accordingly.

Comment: Could not quite comprehend it. Could you please update the fiddle with new expectations?

Comment: Updated in question - "Examples with side menus"

Comment: Hey, are you looking for equal height columns?

Comment: Yes, exactly. So ideally the `#content` height pushes up the `body` height. Then, since the `#sidebar` has `height: 100%`, its height scales with the `#content`.

Comment: There are quite a number of way to achieve that, one of them would be http://css-tricks.com/fluid-width-equal-height-columns/

Answer (score 0):

If you change the height on the html tag to min-height the background color will expand to the whole content.

Comment: I don't think this solution works per requirement (3). Try it on the first jsfiddle - sub-element height won't fill the whole viewport because the body height isn't explicitly defined.